# POP3 problem. Cannot receive mail in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, postfix

I'm having trouble with Thunderbird. Again.

When I click Get Messages it gives me this error:

[image: Get Mail Error]

When I click OK I get this:

[image: Login Failed]

I tried to enter a new password. changed the user password twice but it only goes back to the first error. So does Retry…

What's the issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Looks like `pop3.email.com` doesn't like your authentication credentials. I don't think has anything to do with neither Thunderbird nor Ubuntu. Can you log in correctly from the webmail (if any)?

Comment: yes I can @MrShunz

Comment: Can you then try, from a terminal on your Ubuntu machine, to access the POP3 server via `telnet`? Just type `telnet pop3.email.com 110 <press ENTER>`. When connected, `user yasmin@email.com <press ENTER>` then `pass YOURPASSWORD <press ENTER>` and see if any error is reported?

Comment: @MrShunz when I typed telnet pop3.email.com it says *Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused*

Comment: Syntax is `telnet pop3.email.com 110`, you have to specify port 110 (the POP3 port).

Comment: ok thank you :) so when i entered the password it gave me this error(ERR [AUTH] Authentication failed.) the rest is +OK

Comment: Well, then your username/password is not accepted by the server. I suggest you open a support ticket with your email provider. If the same user/password works ok via web but not via POP3 it can only be resolved by the provider.

Comment: @MrShunz is it possible to do that with postfix